# Why isn't my 8-bit pointer updating correctly?

Tags: c

Directions are here:

I'm supposed to convert the ASCII string in the exact same input buffer, which is in this case `pt1`. 
Unfortunately for me, the loop is executed only once and hence my output buffer only contains the first short value.

I'm trying to convert the ASCII string into a Unicode 16-bit string. According to the directions, `pt1` is supposed to point to an ASCII string.
Expected Output is on this link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/COpXl.jpg

```
void Convert(unsigned short *pt1) { 
    // pt1 is a pointer to a null-terminated variable length ASCII string
    // 0x30 0x31 0x32 0x00 (sentinel value)
    unsigned char *pt2 = (unsigned char *)pt1;
    unsigned char value = *pt2;
    while (*pt2 != 0x00) {
        value = *pt2;
        *pt1 = (unsigned short)value;
        pt2++;
        pt1++;
    }
    *pt1 = 0x0000;
}
```

Comment: @lurker I changed it to 1 since 0x32 is one byte away from 0x31 but the error still persists.

Comment: `pt3` is an uninitialized pointer. So `*pt3 =...` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @lurker changed pt3 to point to the same location where pt1 is pointing to

Comment: Now `*pt3 = ....` is stomping all over the data `*pt2` is trying to read.

Comment: Why is `pt1` an `unsigned short*` and not `char*` (or `unsigned char*`) in the first place?  And why do you bother with `pt3`?  What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to convert an ASCII string to UTF-16 or something?

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm trying to convert an ASCII string to  UTF-16. According to the directions, pt1 is a pointer to an ASCII string.

Comment: Is it required that you do it *in-place*?  That seems like a really bad idea, especially since you have no guarantee that `pt1` has enough bytes allocated to it.  You surely want to explicitly allocate a separate buffer for your UTF-16 output.

Comment: no it's not required that I do it in-place. I'm considering doing it in a separate buffer though, but I don't know how large to allocate the separate buffer, given pt1.

Comment: On your second iteration, if `pt2` points to `0x32` -- what happens on your next iteration?

Comment: please provide a clarification do you want to change the value that is pt1 or memory location?, since `sizeof(unsigned short )== 2` byte and `sizeof(unsigned char ) == 1`, maybe this is something that could not be done, but if you trying to change the value that is settle to this variables (as I'm supposing because your while(*pt2!=0x00)) you could do it by `++(*pt2)` and this you update the value of that variable and you can get rid of this while loop, and maybe you won't need pt3.

Comment: @j.doe An ASCII character takes 2 bytes in UTF-16.  You just need to allocate a buffer of size `(strlen(pt2) + 1) * 2` bytes. (The `+ 1` is for the terminating `NUL`.)

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm not allowed to use strlen() methods or any methods whatsoever in the string class.

Comment: @j.doe Then implement your own `strlen`.  It's straightforward.

Comment: How are you expecting to convert a string of 8-bit characters into a string of 16-bit characters in place? The second one will require double the memory. Are you sure you understood the question correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- Your conversion function does not produce anything visible for the caller: you store code point values into a local array and return to the caller. The compiler warns you that at least `pt3` is set and not used, but a more advanced compiler would optimise away all code for this function without a side effect.
- What is the API description for `Convert`? You seem to receive a pointer to an ASCII string disguised as a pointer to `unsigned short`, and it seems the conversion should be performed in place. If this is the actual requirement, it is a very bad idea. The function should receive a pointer to a destination array with type `unsigned short *`, a `size_t` specifying the number of elements of this array and a pointer to the source string, with type `const char *`.
- How should bytes outside the ASCII range be handled? Is the source string encoded in a given code page? it is UTF-8 encoded? Should the function report an error?

From the EDIT, you seem to confirm the insane API requirement. Assuming there is enough space in the argument array, you should perform the conversion from the last byte to the first, thus avoiding stepping on your own toes:

```c
void Convert(unsigned short *pt1) { 
    // pt1 is a pointer to a null-terminated variable length ASCII string
    // with enough space to receive the converted value including a null terminator
    unsigned char *pt2 = (unsigned char *)pt1;
    size_t i;
    // Compute the number of bytes
    for (i = 0; pt2[i] != '\0'; i++)
        continue;
    // Convert the contents from right to left
    // Assuming ISO8859-1 encoding for bytes outside the ASCII range
    for (;;) {
        pt1[i] = (unsigned short)pt2[i];
        if (i-- == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```